# Confirm box before opening a New Tab with "expr:href"

Tags: javascript, blogger

At blogger I tried to make a confirmation box appear before opening a new tab for whatsapp-web share button

```
<html>
<a class='whatsapp' data-confirm="Some Question?"
    expr:href='&quot;https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=&quot; + data:post.title + &quot; &gt;&gt; &quot; + data:post.url' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>Share Web Whatsapp</a>
</html>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var openTab = document.querySelectorAll('.whatsapp');

    for (var i = 0; i < openTab.length; i++) {
      openTab[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          var choice = confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm'));

          if (choice) {
            window.location.href = this.getAttribute('expr:href');
          }
      });
    }
    </script>
```

The problem is when i click yes the link won't load

Comment: Why your condition statement in for loop contains a `&lt;` ?
You can try this `for (var i = 0; i < openTab.length; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
The content of the body element is displayed in your browser.
<a href="https://dzone.com/articles/xamarinforms-styling-with-css"
 target="_blank" onclick="preventProp(event)">click me</a>
</body>
<script>
function preventProp(e){
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to open this link ?")){
   return true;
  }
  else{
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Note: You can't open a link inside Stack Overflow's code editor. Please copy the code and try it in your editor.

Remember: You can still open the link by RightClick->OpenLinkInNewTab.